# What is the difference between Data Ingestion and ETL?

Tags: etl, data-ingestion

I have raw data present on a NOSQL database. My requirement is to apply some customization for further data processing and write it on a graphical DB. I have been exploring ETL tools on trial basis and some of them have Data ingestion and ETL features separately. Hence, I would like to know whether Data ingestion solves my problem or ETL ??

Comment: As the terms “data ingestion” and “ETL” have no standard definitions, your question is unanswerable. All you need to consider is whether a tool meets your requirements - not whether a particular vendor classifies a piece of functionality as ingestion or etl. Bear in mind that asking for tool recommendations on this site is off topic